# How to configure Sonarqube for multi module Java Ant project through build.xml

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, multi-module

I am having a multi module Java Ant project. It contains a root directory and its sub modules. And each sub module having its own build file and the root having the parent build file for calling the child one.

```
Z
build.xml
 -- A
     -- build.xml
 -- B
     -- build.xml
 -- C
     -- build.xml
```

Here Z is root directory and A, B and C and sub module.

I am able to configure for each module separately without any issue. But not able to combine those into a single report.

Regards, 
Unni

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs on [how to manually configure a multi-module project](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages). You'll need to translate a little bit for the SonarQube Scanner for Ant, but it will give you the basic idea.

Essentially:

```
<property name="sonar.modules" value="A,B,C"/>
<property name="A.sonar.projectName" value="Module A"/>
<property name="A.sonar...." value="..."/>
<!-- and so on -->
```

You'll need to configure all modules' properties in the parent *build.xml*. Then for analysis, first build all the child modules, then run analysis of all modules from the parent *build.xml*.

Comment: Hi Ann, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @UnnikrishnanMuraleedharan if you find my answer helpful, you might consider accepting it :)

Comment: Hi Ann, actually I have tried these. But when its come to sonar analysis part in the child build xmls it is getting failing in Process project properties. Could you please let me know how can we flow these properties from parent to child.

Comment: See my addition @UnnikrishnanMuraleedharan